# How do I convert a lot of IP addresses to URLs in Python? Is this possible?

Tags: python-3.x, security

I have a .csv file with a bunch of IP addresses. I am looking for a way to run a script to import the file and convert them to URLs and maybe export them to another .csv or something similar. Is this possible? How would I do this? Admittedly, I am a novice when it comes to python. I have done enough research to know that a call to sockets is involved, but that's where the trail ends. I don't know where to go from there. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of urls?

Comment: What do you mean by "converting an IP address to URL"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: for example if given the IP address 64.223.177.99, the script would return with http://www.google.com, with full http:// included or if it is an ftp then ftp://. This is what I mean by URL. If I need to clarify further, please advise.

Comment: There is this IP address for example: 151.101.193.69. How can you tell whether it's a website, an ftp, an imap, an nntp or whatever else server? Not even portmapping would fully help with that. Also the mapping is absolutely not one to one, multiple services may be provided on one IP address, how would you choose the url?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert them to specific URL's, but I guess you want to get the domain names. This is called **Reverse DNS Lookup**.
You can run this command `nslookup <IP-ADDRESS>` and get the domain name (besides other info).

Example:

```
nslookup 75.126.153.206
```

However, this does not guarantee that only that domain is associated with that IP. This is due to load balancers, and you will get the load balancer's domain name as a result most of the times. To avoid that you can try to do a **Reverse IP Lookup**. This will provide you all the domains associated with that IP address (online example https://hackertarget.com/reverse-ip-lookup).

Besides that, detecting the protocol (http/s, ftp) is another story. You have to scan the targets for specific ports like 80 (http), 443 (https), 21 (ftp) etc. to verify for they services they run. Again this does not guarantee that a service is definitively running on default ports (like web servers a lot of time may run on 8080 or some other port). To avoid that you may need to scan for a wider range of ports and detect their services which will be far more time consuming and you may get into trouble by getting your IP banned since somewhere this may be considered illegal.

Anyway for port scanning I suggest you to take a look at Nmap (https://nmap.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

def ip_to_url(ip):
    try:
        r = requests.get(f'http://{ip}', timeout=1).url
        return r
    except:
        return 'not found'

print(ip_to_url('142.250.189.238'))
```

###### Output

```
http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: Could you please add a description/some comments/documentation in the code indicating why/how your code works?